# Row-wise aggregation of two DataFrames in Spark

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

I have two Dataframes df_A & df_B where columns in df_B are a subset of columns in df_A. Apart from one unique identifier columns, rest all columns are LongType. What I'm trying to achieve is using uuid to row-wise aggregate the columns present in both B & A else keep columns of A intact.

```
df_A.schema
# StructType(List(StructField(custom_uuid,StringType,true),
  StructField(custom_col1,LongType,true),
  StructField(custom_col2,LongType,true),
  StructField(custom_col3,LongType,true),
  StructField(custom_col4,LongType,true)))
df_B.schema
# StructType(List(StructField(custom_uuid,StringType,true),
  StructField(custom_col1,LongType,true),
  StructField(custom_col2,LongType,true),
  StructField(custom_col3,LongType,true)))
```

I wasn't able to find a direct solution for this problem and I'm able to use union over dataframes by first adding missing columns to B and taking a Union.

```
for missing_column in missing_columns: # 100-200 missing columns
    df_B = df_B.withColumn(missing_column,lit(None).cast(LongType()))
df_final = df_A.union(df_B)
```

Then on the final dataset, I aggregate based on uuid to achieve the result.

```
col_sums = [sparkSum(col(col_name)) for col_name in df_final.schema.names]
aggregated_df = df_final
    .groupBy("custom_uuid")
    .agg(*col_sums)
```

But this seems to be a lengthy approach to the problem as it involves following steps in sequence:

- Appending missing columns to the subset Dataframe
- Taking Union of Dataframes
- Aggregating after taking the union

Is there any other approach to make the aggregation more efficient? There could be a difference of 100-200 columns between df_A and df_B. Also, rows in df_B could be lower than the rows in df_A ( mimimum rows= 20million). Or is there perhaps some other efficient approach besides using spark (eg: orderby(uuid) on dataframes and use something else for the task).

Comment: Hi, I'm facing the same issue right now, did you ever find an optimal solution to this problem ?